# I receive this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pagination' of undefined"

Tags: angular

[Here is my object from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IGW8.png)
I have in my template this code for pagination:

```
<ul class="pagination-custom text-right">
  <li class="pag-link"><a (click)="onClick(customers.meta.pagination.current_page - 1)"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a></li>
  <li class="pag-link" *ngFor="let item of createRange(customers.meta.pagination.total_pages); let i = index">
    <a (click)="onClick(i + 1)">{{i + 1}}</a></li>
  <li class="pag-link"><a (click)="onClick(customers.meta.pagination.current_page + 1)"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

here is my function onClick()

```
  onClick(number) {
    this.CustomersData.page(number).subscribe(
      r => {this.customers  = r;
      });
  }
```

and here is page()

```
  page(number) {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers?page=' + (number), {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization',
        this.token.t)});
  }
```

> Problem is that function works fine but I receive this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pagination' of undefined" in my console from the start

Comment: How does your customer object look like ? Does it have `meta` key in it ... Also check if you are getting `this.customers` is undefined .. console.log to check it !

Comment: If you just wanna avoid this error, you can put *ngIf condition on the list for customers.meta. Although it would be better to check the value in component for the same.

Comment: yes, I have meta I post an image in my question with object

Comment: and if I will write in my ts console.log(this.customers.meta) will show the same problem " in src/app/customers/customers.component.ts(26,20): error TS2339: Property 'meta' does not exist on type 'object'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a `ternary` operator before accessing the key.

```
<ul class="pagination-custom text-right">
  <li class="pag-link"><a (click)="onClick(customers?.meta?.pagination?.current_page - 1)"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a></li>
  <li class="pag-link" *ngFor="let item of createRange(customers.meta.pagination.total_pages); let i = index">
    <a (click)="onClick(i + 1)">{{i + 1}}</a></li>
  <li class="pag-link"><a (click)="onClick(customers.meta.pagination.current_page + 1)"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```